# How to load a file's contents into a variable/define in NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis

I have a file 'releaseVersionNumber.txt' which I read during my build process; currently its read for my Mac build but I want to read it in my Windows NSIS build to reduce the number of edit locations (duplication being evil)...

So I'm trying to replace:

```
!define VERSION 1.2.3
```

with something like

```
FileOpen $4 "..\releaseVersionNumber.txt" r
FileRead $4 $1
FileClose $4
!define VERSION ${1}
```

But I get an error **command FileOpen not valid outside Section or Function**. Wrapping it in a function I produces **command call not valid outside Section or Function** so I can't seem to do this in the installer setup, only at runtime.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?!

Comment: Getting another issue now after using !define /file - this doesn't work: `VIProductVersion "${VERSION}.0"` gives me _Error: invalid VIProductVersion format, should be X.X.X.X_ ...

Comment: Turns out the variable isn't being set as expected - the !define /file is loading "1.2?" - no idea what's up with that but adding 4/5 blanks at the end fixes it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All commands begining with `!` are [compile time commands](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html), so they are processed at compile time, much before your program runs.

- You can try declaring `VERSION` as a **Variable** instead of a define:

  ```
  Var VERSION
  FileOpen $4 "..\releaseVersionNumber.txt" r
  FileRead $4 $VERSION
  FileClose $4
  ```
- If you need `VERSION` to be a define, then you can try the `/file` parameter in [!define](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.4.1).

  ```
  !define /file VERSION "..\releaseVersionNumber.txt"
  ```
- I like to have a `version.nsh` file with just the define:

  ```
  !define VERSION "2013-03-25:16:23:50"
  ```

  And then, I include it:

  ```
  !include /NONFATAL version.nsh
  # Default value in case no version.nsh is present
  !ifndef VERSION
      !define /date VERSION "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  !endif
  ```

Comment: !define /file is the one for me!